# How to style menu in CSS to look like a button

Tags: html, css, button, menu

I would like to style joomla 3.x menu to look like a button - it looks like a button, changing colours on hover, active item displayed correctly but link does not work in the way I want - I must point with the mouse directly on the text to open the link and I would like to point anywhere in the button area to open the link....

My page code looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-101 current active parent"><a href="/" >Item 1</a></li>
<li class="item-102 parent"><a href="/index.php/item2" >Item 2</a></li>
<li class="item-103 parent"><a href="/index.php/item3" >Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

my CSS looks like this:

```
#menu /* layout main menu */
{
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  margin-top:1em;
  padding-bottom:1em;
  width:100%;
  background-color:gimgrey;
  background-image:url('/templates/swimming/images/logo.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

ul.menu
{
   display: table;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 0em;
}

div#menu li /* horizontal menu layout */
{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1em;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right:30px;
  background-color: #4180dd;
}

div#menu li a:hover /* link style on-mouse-over */
{
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;

}

div#menu li:hover  /* button style on-mouse-over */
{
  padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1em;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #dd417f;
}

div#menu li a /* link style */
{
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

div#menu li.active a /* active menu item style */
{
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div#menu li.active /* active menu button style */
{
  padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1em;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #dd417f;
}
```

Without joomla I would do it vice versa `<a href><li></li></a>` to get the effect I need (to have as a link whole li area not only the text).

What am I doing wrong? Any advice?

Thanks,
Zdenka

Comment: Try `div#menu li a { display: block; }` cause you are currently using `inline-block`

Comment: Apply the visual styling (padding, background colour, border, etc)to the `<a>` tag instead of the `<li>` tag but leave the `display:inline` and `margin` where it is.

Comment: First of all, you applied a padding to your `li` – which means the `a` within it will of course not take up all the space. Give the padding to the `a` instead. Second of all, your CSS is highly redundant – you keep repeating properties like padding, borders and border-radius for the different “states” of your items, which is just unnecessary …

Comment: Keep in mind for the future that `<a><li></li></a>` is not valid HTML

Comment: Your CSS is also all over the shop, your a mixing  class `.menu` with id `#menu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nobloss/ybn6v0o1/1/)):

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="item-101 current active parent"><a href="/">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-102 parent"><a href="/index.php/item2">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-103 parent"><a href="/index.php/item3">Item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu
/* layout main menu */
 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:gimgrey;
    background-image:url('/templates/swimming/images/logo.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
ul.menu {
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0em;
}
.menu li
/* horizontal menu layout */
 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    background-color: #4180dd;
}
.menu li a:hover
/* link style on-mouse-over */
 {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li:hover
/* button style on-mouse-over */
 {
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #dd417f;
}
.menu li a
/* link style */
 {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1em;
}
.menu li.active a
/* active menu item style */
 {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li.active
/* active menu button style */
 {
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #dd417f;
}
```

What I've done:

- consistantly used class
- Renoved `div#menu` which is looking for a div with ID of "menu"
- Channged your `li` to `inline-block` and removed padding
- Put the padding on the `a` tags, this will make their "target areas" bigger

Comment: Thanks, great it works. I only had to change it a bit because of logo position. </br> `#menu
{
 clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:gimgrey;
    background-image:url('/templates/plavani/images/grafika/logo.png');
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.menu /* layout main menu */
 {
    float:right;
    padding-right: 0em;
    width:40%;
    display:inline;
}`